# How should I handle titles of sources in foreign languages in APA?

Tags: research-process, citations

How should I handle titles of sources in foreign languages in APA?

For example, the title of the source is in Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google yielded [this](http://libguides.msvu.ca/content_mobile.php?pid=377145):

> Book/article titles and names written in Latin-based scripts (French, Spanish, German, etc.) can be cited with only minor adjustments.
> Provide a translation of the title in square brackets. Do not translate names written in Latin-based scripts.
>
> Titles and names written in non-Latin scripts (Chinese, Arabic, Russian, etc.) must be transliterated before translating and citing. If you are uncomfortable transliterating material yourself, don't guess -- get help!
> Titles should be transliterated and translated into English.
> Names should be transliterated (not translated) and arranged in "Western" order, e.g., ordered by surname in reference list.

(Follow the link to see examples)